# Is it possible to create CSS border triangle with odd side size?

Tags: html, css

I can create a tirangle using CSS trick with border, e.g:

```css
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;

  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

(from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

But, as you can see, it always has an even side length. It happens because it consists of two border sides - left and right. If I make one side shorter than other - it doesn't solve the problem, I only get not a equilateral triangle. If I have a triangle with odd side in design picture, I can use this method.

I think, **transform** could help, but I'm not sure, it's a good and strict enough method.

Is there any other solutions?

Comment: Are you saying you want to create a scalene triangle? Could you provide an idea of what you are looking to produce?

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696143/8620333 (you will find all the type of triangle)

Comment: @Martin, I am talking about isosceles triangles, with two equal sides. It may be a scalene triangle. E.g.: up/down triangles here for voting. Stackoverflow.com uses svg icons for them. They also has even horisontal side size (32 px) and two pixels at upside and downside vertices.
I interested in css tiangles with odd horisontal side and one pixel vertices.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thank you! Something good enough I can see in "CSS3 triangles with transform rotate" answer. It has 1 pixel vertex. But when I zoom it in, I can see it has different gradients on left and right sides. So it's not presise isosceles triangle after rotation.

Answer (score 1):

I would stretch the triangle using `transform` by increasing the `Y`-scale

```css
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;

  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
  transform: scaleY(1.66);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-down"></div>
```

Comment: Thanx, I ran you code as a snipped, and zoomed in the trianle. But it has not equal left and right sides. It's not an isosceles triangle. I can see 2 pixels on the bottom vertex: light red and very light red. I use FireFox 72.